# No tooltips on Chart JS line graph

Tags: tooltip, chart.js

I must be missing something obvious but I can't  get tooltips to work on this chartjs line graph. Do I have to tune them on in some way?

```
 Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#FFF';

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                   // labels: chartdata.labels,
                   // datasets: dataset
                    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
                },
                options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero:true
                                    }
                                }]
                            },
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Custom Chart Title'
                            },
                             legend: {
                                display:false,
                            },
                             tooltips: {
                    mode: 'label',


                        },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'label'
                },
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chart.js, array of colors for the `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` properties are for bar-type charts for instance, since you have different elements in your graph (several bars).

In the line-type, you only have one element (the line, with the fill below), so you need to set these properties with a single color.

---

If you change these properties to :

```js
datasets: [{
    label: '# of Votes',
    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    borderWidth: 1
}]
```

You will get the following result, which you can check [at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrLg2j37/) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, I would never have found that answer. Thought it was a global setting or something.

Comment: @LeBlaireau A pleasure ! Yeah it is not the kind of information you will find in the documentation

Comment: Why x axis labels are not visible??

Comment: @AmulyaAcharya They are, but displayed in white so you can't see them clearly on a grey background

Comment: @tektiv Thanks a lot, I got it.